# Approximation Theory, Hyperplane, Proximinal Set

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $V \subset X$ be a hyperplane. Prove that if there exists a vector $x_0 \in X-V $ such that the set $P_V(x_0)$ is nonempty, than $V$ is a proximinal set in $X$.